# Magento Static Block not being called from layout file

Tags: xml, magento, content-management-system, magento-1.7

I've modified the `<cms_index_index>` tag of local.xml to ideally pull a static block from the database when the homepage loads. However, no static block is being pulled. I've created a static block with identifier mobile_home, and it's enabled. I also tried with an existing, working static block to no avail. What's wrong? And what might get this working?

```
<cms_index_index>
      <block type="cms/block" name="cms_page"><action method="setBlockId"><block_id>mobile_home</block_id></action></block>
</cms_index_index>
```

Edit: After adding a reference, it still doesn't render:

```
<cms_index_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="cms/block" name="cms_page"><action method="setBlockId"><block_id>mobile_home</block_id></action></block>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
```

Answer (score 2):

The block is being instantiated (assuming this layout XML is being merged), but it needs to be added to the flow of rendering. A quick test is to take your block and make it an output block via the `output` attribute:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <block type="cms/block" name="cms_page" output="toHtml">
        <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>mobile_home</block_id>
        </action>
     </block>
</cms_index_index>
```

You can then add it to an template-less block such as `content`:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <!-- or use reference syntax, up to you -->
    <block type="cms/block" name="cms_page" parent="content">
        <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>mobile_home</block_id>
        </action>
     </block>
</cms_index_index>
```

You could also go into the content body of your CMS page and add the static block using a block directive (or inserting via the widget interface):

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="mobile_home"}}
```

or

```
{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="5"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately the static block still isn't rendering! Please see Edit above

Comment: The `head` block is the html head - it isn't visible! Try the `content` block.